# Can't access value attribute of mutable state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state

I can't access the value attribute of the mutable state.

Neither the date or events I can access.

I asked multiple AI's and searched the web. No solution found.

Strange behavior. Didn't have such problems anywhen.

Probably ChatGPT is the traitor in this code...

If you'd help me, I'd be glad.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
// Function for displaying event rows
fun EventRows(api: ApiWrapper, pageCount: Int, pagerState: PagerState, height: Dp) {
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, pageCount = pageCount) { page ->
        val date = remember(page) {
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(page.toLong())
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        }
        // date.value not accessable
        val events by remember(date) {
            mutableStateOf(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { api.getEvents(date) })
        }
        // events.value not accessable

        Column(modifier = Modifier.height(height)) {
            LazyColumn {
                // events.value needed here, but not accessable
                itemsIndexed(events.value.toTypedArray()){ index, event ->
                    EventRow(event)
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe change `val date = remember(page) {` to `val date by remember(page) {`?

Comment: It also seems to me like `events` will have type `MutableState<Job>` because `launch` just returns a `Job`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that you are using a delegate
Here is the difference between `=` and `by`

You do like this:

```
val events by remember(date) { ... }
```

So you need to call just `events` and not `events.value`. Because this is what actually do this `by` word. This allows you to skip `value`.

So, here is how you need to use it:

```
val events by remember(date) { ... }
...
itemsIndexed(
    events.toTypedArray()){ index, event ->
        EventRow(event)
        Divider()
    }
```

Or, you can remove delegate and make it like this:

```
val events = remember(date) { ... }
...
itemsIndexed(
    events.value.toTypedArray()){ index, event ->
        EventRow(event)
        Divider()
    }
```

Notice that if you need to update the value of `events` this requires making `events` `var` and not `val`

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
val events by ...
```

to

```
var events by ...
```

The keyword **val** is used for read-only variables.

You can also use like this:

```
val events = remember(date) { mutableStateOf(...) }
events.value = ...
```

In this case we don't use the delegate `by` to access to the state.